# a plsql code increment the counter per 100 record using exit when condition

Tags: plsql

here is a table having 2000 records i need to update the table with some given condition

```
update tablename
  set counter=1
  where counter=null and
        rownum<500
```

for first execution so that counter should be 4 at last of 2000 rows execn,

```
EXIT WHEN counter > 500; -- LOOP until condition is met
```

loop will execute some sql

```
update tablename
  set counter=1
  where counter=null and
        rownum<500
```

the script will have to run until the conditions of that update state meant are met , I want to run a function that does that automatically for me until the condition is complete(condition is update statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a cursor and 2 counters.
You can add the update code somewhere.

```
DECLARE 
  CURSOR MY_CURSOR IS  SELECT rowid, object_name  FROM  <MYTABLE> ;   
  COUNTER NUMBER :=0;  
  COUNTER_GROUP NUMBER :=0; 
  begin  
  FOR MYCUR IN MY_CURSOR LOOP
   EXIT WHEN COUNTER_GROUP > 10 ;
         BEGIN      
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(MYCUR.object_name || ' COUNTER ' || COUNTER || ' COUNTER_GROUP ' || COUNTER_GROUP); 
            COUNTER := COUNTER + 1 ;
            SELECT  floor (( COUNTER - 1 )/500) + 1 INTO COUNTER_GROUP     FROM dual;                    
UPDATE <MYTABLE> SET  counter = COUNTER_GROUP WHERE ROWID =  MYCUR.rowid ;    
                EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR =>  ' || SQLERRM);
          END;
  END LOOP ;  
  END;  
  /
```

Comment: Thanks Jean...but the output should come like - 200 recods have counter = 1, 400 records have counter= 2, 600 records have counter =3,i need to update the table and the counter value each time the rownum value is less than 200 in exit when statement using plsql,this code is workin fine but this code is not in respect of tables.

Comment: @sonaa it's not clear for me, I think you need to update your question.

Comment: ok,..I will explain you ....the script will have to run until the conditions of that update statement are met so,suppose if we have 600 records ,if 600/200=3 should come  if it is executed for 3 times ,and update statement should be inside exit when statement...please let me know if it is clear..

Comment: I think I understand better, I changed my code with a second counter, you can add update in the script

Comment: :EXIT WHEN counter > 100; -- LOOP until condition is met 
loop will execute some sql
 update tablename set counter=1 where counter=null and rownum<100
 the script will have to run until the conditions of that update state meant are met , I want to run a function that does that automatically for me until the condition is complete(condition is update statement)
eg
there is a table 
having 2000 records
i need to update the table with some given condition
update tablename set counter=1 where counter=null and rownum<500 for first execution
so that counter should be 4 at last of 2000 rows execn

Comment: Can you please help me on the same.

Comment: Hi Jean : are you there??

Comment: @sonaa hello you have already marked this question as answered, what do you ask ?

Comment: Hi Jean ,It is not answered fully

Comment: OK I understand in this case I think you should update your question

Comment: Since it's more clear, I updated my answer with an update clause using rowid.

Comment: Hi Jean,Can you please guide me to improve my plsql coding skills,or if you can share some of the links from where i can practice coding .That will be really a  great help . Thanks Jean

Comment: if it is throwing some errors it's better you give the message here.If you are a begoinner just google pl/sql tutorial or sql plus tutorial.

Comment: Thanks Jean for guidance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
 CURSOR c1 IS
 SELECT * FROM all_objects ;
 counter INT:=0;
 TYPE c1_typ IS TABLE OF c1%ROWTYPE;
 c1_tbl c1_typ;
BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
   FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO c1_tbl LIMIT 200;
   counter := counter+1;
   EXIT WHEN counter>10;
   dbms_output.put_line(200*COUNTER ||' RECORDS GOT PROCESSED .COUNTER :'||counter); 
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: It just look like a copy paste of the code of my answer and you made my same initial mistake of exiting when counter is 10 and not 100 (what I have corrected) ;-)

Comment: Counter is expected to increase by 1 per 100 records.and its not a copy of yours. Check tyr limilt clause to restrict extraction at 100 rec.

Comment: Thanks Prashant...but the output should come like - 200 recods have counter = 1, 400 records have counter= 2, 600 records have counter =3,i need to update the table and the counter value each time the rownum value is less than 200 in exit when statement using plsql,this code is workin fine but this code is not in respect of tables.

Comment: @Prashant ok I understand now thanks for your feedback

Comment: @Prashant ,Thanks a lot ,it is working fine.how to rate your answer.can you please tell.

Comment: @sonaa : see the upper and lower arrow marks ..left to my answer..Press the upper one ..twice thrice...if you find my answer suitable for your question ;-)

Comment: @Prashant: ok i will follow that,One more Question ,for the same requirement,if i am working on one particular table and it has around 6000 records so in that case ,how should i approach??

Comment: @Prashant : i need to ask few more question on the same

Comment: Yes please. Be sure to provide complete info

Comment: @Prashant:EXIT WHEN counter > 100; -- LOOP until condition is met loop will execute some sql update tablename set counter=1 where counter=null and rownum<100 the script will have to run until the conditions of that update state meant are met , I want to run a function that does that automatically for me until the condition is complete(condition is update statement) eg there is a table having 2000 records i need to update the table with some given condition update tablename set counter=1 where counter=null and rownum<500 for first execution so that counter should be 4 at last of 2000 rows execn

Comment: Can you please help me on the same

Comment: Create a dummy table .. Fill some data.. Then tell me what updates do u wanna mke to this data.. May be i could some idea

Comment: @Prashant: I have already created dummy table,i have already given you update statement..

Comment: sry it is 500 not 100

Comment: if counter column is not there we can create that column according to the dummy table structure,Plz tell me if it is clear now.i think i have explained it now

Comment: Can you get someone who could understand this question..i answered to this initially posted question and answered correctly. Uou pathetically decreased the ratings .great

Comment: @Prashant :my requirement got changed